# How to include GeoPDF support for GDAL on OSX?

Tags: gdal, mac, geopdf

I have installed GDAL 2.2.1 and Poppler using homebrew

```
brew install gdal
brew install poppler
```

Everything seems to be working correctly but I cannot translate a GeoPDF to a GeoTiffs.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff source.pdf dest.tiff
ERROR 4: `source.pdf' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

And there doesn't seem to be a driver available to it

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep PDF
```

Any idea how I would go about including GeoPDF support?

Answer (score 1):

It does not help to install GDAL and Poppler if your GDAL version is built without Poppler. The documentation http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html gives advice for building:

> Unix build
>
> The relevant configure options are --with-poppler, --with-podofo,
>   --with-podofo-lib and --with-podofo-extra-lib-for-test.

Of course for you only --with-poppler is relevant, and further:

> Poppler
>
> libpoppler itself must have been configured with --enable-xpdf-headers
>   so that the xpdf C++ headers are available. Note: the poppler C++ API
>   isn't stable, so the driver compilation may fail with too old or too
>   recent poppler versions. Successfully tested versions are poppler >=
>   0.12.X and <= 0.31.0.

Answer (score 1):

I spent several days trying to compile GDAL with poppler to no avail.  I'm still keen for an answer by no matter what I tried, configuring GDAL `--with-poppler` always failed the compilation check and it wouldn't add support.

Fortunately, I found an alternative with another package installer called Miniconda.

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh 
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install gdal
gdalinfo --formats
```